# CVE-2016-5195 Dirty Cow on Android

Tags: linux, android, kernel

I was wondering if there is a possibility to exploit the CVE-2016-5195 vulnerability on Android?

Since Android runs on linux kernel, I would expect the answer to be yes.
Yet, I was not able to find any mentions online.

**EDIT:**
This question was marked as duplicate, however, I would like to keep it, so that it is focused on the impact on Android, rather than general impact of the vulnerability.

Comment: https://github.com/timwr/CVE-2016-5195

Comment: If you have a more specific question(s) about Dirty COW on Android you could ask that, but as it stands now this question is completely covered by the duplicate in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/oct/21/dirty-cow-linux-vulnerability-found-after-nine-years (near the end of the article) seems to say its a YES.